# Weight paint does not reflect only the number 0

Tags: weight-painting

I'm using Google Translate.
Weight paint does not reflect only the number 0.
why?
How can I solve it?[This is the problem part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVSnS.jpg)

Comment: It looks like because you are using an _Add Brush,_ adding 0 has 0 effect. If you want to remove weight, change to a _Subtract Brush_ (you will still need a value higher than 0). If you want the Weight value to affect what you paint directly (ie. Weight of 0.5 changes the selected area to 0.5), use a __Draw Brush__

Comment: I don't know why a Weight value of 0 doesn't give a result of 0 in Blend > Mix though, another problem is that I don't understand why black color is not displayed by default, some will think that there is no weight with blue color which is not the case

Comment: @moonboots Well, blue means weight is zero OR that the weight is virtually zero because the vertex is not part of the group. Like having no money in the bank regardless of wether or not one has an account.

Comment: a vertex can be part of a group with a weight of 0.01 and it will appear blue, that's the problem, it's misleading

Comment: solved.
The cause was a brush.
It worked when I made a subtraction.
Thank you very much.